# How to record using microphone and save it in local disk drive?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, microphone

I got the code

```
var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone(); 
mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true); 
mic.setLoopBack(true);
```

when I browse thru adobe documentation for microphone access. But I could not find a way to record the sound and save it in the local drive.
How to store the sound in local drive???

Thank you  for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To capture microphone audio, listen
>   for the sampleData events dispatched
>   by a Microphone instance. The
>   SampleDataEvent object dispatched for
>   this event contains the audio data.
>   [© as3 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html)

so you need to record [`SampleDataEvent.data`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html#data)s to a `ByteArray` and then save it with [`FileReference.save()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

One step you'll **need** to complete is making sure your application is developed as an AIR Application. You won't have access to saving a file unless this is the case.

As for the recording, here's [a really great package](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1858) you can use for this.

Comment: @Marty... Adobe AIR application? Can I use it in iOS or Android devices?

Comment: That's out of my scope of knowledge; would you mind adding those tags to the question if those devices are your target?

Comment: @Marty... Thanks , I was just asking coz i saw that options in CS5.5

Comment: I think it would work, not 100% sure. Pretty sure it's very similar.